Generate graph edges based on region boundaries on image
I want to analyze experiment data of particle packing, and specifically calculate things like coordination number. I've managed to autodetect the centroids of each particle using OpenCV thresholding and contour detection. However, when it comes to creating the graph/network, I'm drawing a blank on how to detect edges based on contact of each region. My (failed) attempts have been:

Using GraphTools with knn and geometric: It's subject to a fixed number of edges per particle, and in my case there will be regions with more or less edges than the specified number.
Using KDTree and queries: there is no fixed distance to query neighbors with contact
Voronoi/Delaunay from scikit: forces cells that are 'voids' in the experiment
Griottes: a package to analyze biological tissue, but it generates redundant graphs and edges

My idea is to skeletonize the image to obtain the edges of each particle and then create an edge only if it's orthogonal to the skeleton but I'm not sure how to proceed.
Thanks in advance!
Tagged particles
Image from experiments

Which programming language do you use? Please add a sketch of the desired output and some code that shows where you got stuck!
